# use custom validator to disable textbox if another is empty

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

In my project I have to give user option to put a security question and answer to this question, so I have two textboxes one for question and another one for the answer, I want to use ASP.net custom validators to do this task so if question textbox is empty answer textbox will be disabled and when question textbox is not empty answer textbox is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is good enough here:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var minimumQuestionLength = 20;

function checkQuestionBox()
  {
    var questionLength=document.getElementById("question").value.length;

    if(questionLength < minimumQuestionLength)
    {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="myHeader">Test</h1> 
<p>Question: <input type="text" id="question"/><br />
Answer: <input type="text" id="answer" onkeypress="return checkQuestionBox();"/>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Fairly simple. You can also disable "answer" on start and then enable once the question is correct, if you prefer that option. Also simple JavaScript.

Comment: Note that this one is down and dirty and has not been checked to see if there are gotchas in some browsers you have to code for. You can set up the JavaScript as a custom validation script and handle it that way, but it is a bit more time consuming than what I have done above.

Answer (score 1):

A validator is not fired if the textbox is empty. But you can set the attribute ValidateEmptyText="true" on your CustomValidator to bypass this.